# JIRA ScriptRunner Multiplying 2 CustomFieldValues error

Tags: groovy, jira

I am trying to multiply two CustomFieldValues but end up with the following errors:

[image: error]

Here is the code:

[image: Code]

What can be done to resolve the errors?

Edit1:
I changed my totalInstanceCost calculation to:
[image: parsing]

but still receive the errors:

[image: error2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
totalInstanceCost = instanceString * usageString * 31
```

to

```
totalInstanceCost = Double.parseDouble(instanceString.toString()) * 
                    Double.parseDouble(usageString.toString()) * 31
```

Comment: sorry if the code is unclear, but the instanceString CustomFieldValues outputs decimals.  I will try to parse the calculation with double or float and let you know how it goes

Comment: @time_yates It worked perfectly! thanks for the quick responses.  All i need to do now is import a number formatter for the decimal places

Comment: Cool :-)  There's a check box on the left of my answer if you want to accept it :-)